# How to add a folder to every folder called "Photographs"?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I have only recently learned how to add a folder to a folder while currently in it.

I have a couple hundred file folders that each contain a copy of a folder called "Photographs". I want to select each folder called "Photographs" and then add a folder called "drafts" to it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) as follows:

```bash
# Note: 
#  "." targets the current dir; adapt as needed.
#  New-Item outputs a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] instance for
#  each directory it creates; to suppress, append "| Out-Null"
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Directory -Filter Photographs |
  New-Item -Type Directory -Path { $_.FullName } -Name drafts -Force -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note the use of a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (`{ ... }`) to dynamically derive the value for the 
`-Path` parameter from each input object (`$_`).

`-Force` causes `New-Item -Type Directory` to *not* report an error when a target directory by that name already exists (in that event, the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance that is output describes the preexisting, not a newly created directory).